# Type hinting in PhpStorm where argument is same as result

Tags: phpstorm

I have a method results that accepts a class string as argument.

It is something like this:

```
$this->db->get('tasks')->result(Task::class);
```

Can I give a typehint to PhpStorm that the return type of `result` is of the same type as the argument of `result`? So in this case of the `Tasks` type.

I found this, but I didn't got it to work:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: Advanced Metadata is the only way. Otherways -- type hint local variable manually via `@var`.

Comment: @LazyOne Any ideas how the metadata would look in this case? Something like this? `namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override( Db::result(0), type(0));
}`

Comment: I say: 1) Use `map` as in example 2) why just `Db::result(0)`? Class has to be properly namespaced 3) have a look at what [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) generates for Laravel -- it works there. 4) Does `get('tasks')` return instance of `Db`? P.S. It's possible project-reopening might be required (in older IDE versions IDE did not picked up changes straight away; not sure about latest 2017.3)

Comment: `override( CI_DB_result::result(0),
        map( [
            '' => '@[]',
        ]));` This work if I do `(new \CI_DB_result)->result(Task::class)`, but not if  some other class has a method that returns CI_DB_Result. Like `(new Foo)->get()->result(Task::class)`

Comment: Can't really advise on this without playing with actual code myself. Metadata support is not super complete .. so everything is possible (may actually depend on what `get()` returns/how it's declared). At the same time stuff like `$this->make(XXX)` or `$this->app->make(XXX)` works fine.